# How to detect & act on an error in logstash elasticsearch output

Tags: logstash

When using the logstash elasticsearch output, I'm trying to detect any errors, and if an error occurs do something else with the message. Is this possible?

Specifically, I'm using fingerprinting to allocate a document id, and I want to use elasticsearch output action "create" to throw an error if that document id already exists - but in this case I want to push these potential duplicates elsewhere (probably another elasticsearch index) so I can verify that they are in fact duplicates.

Is this possible? It seems like the Dead Letter Queue might do what I want - except that https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#_retry_policy states that 409 conflict errors are ignored.